# Is there a way, through the API, to manage "Sharing"?

Tags: docusignapi

Through the console, you can go to Preferences and under Member Profile you can select Sharing and then chose which users will have the ability to view and manage the folder list of the selected user within their home page folder list.

I was wondering if there was any way to manage this using the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately not -- "Folder Sharing" functionality is not currently available via the DocuSign API (REST or SOAP).